# Deserializing string using ServiceStack

Tags: json, servicestack

I am trying to deserialize a simple json string using ServiceStack to Dto object:

```
public class TestDto
{
    public int MyProp { get; set; }
}

var json = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<TestDto>("{\"MyProp\":6}");
```

I get the exception:

```
[System.TypeInitializationException] = 
{"The type initializer for 'ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonReader`1' threw an exception."}

// With the inner exception:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

// And the stack trace:
at ServiceStack.Text.Common.JsReader`1.GetCoreParseFn[T]()
at ServiceStack.Text.Common.JsReader`1.GetParseFn[T]()
at ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonReader`1..cctor()
```

I am developing in Visual Studio using Xamarin on Windows 8.1. The ServiceStack code is located inside a portable library. At the moment I am triggering the portable library code directly from a unit test.

Here is the Nuget package info for ServiceStack:

```
<package id="ServiceStack.Text" version="4.0.36" 
targetFramework="portable-net45+win+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10" />
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: What version of SS.Text are you using? What Platform/OS are you running this on? and please provide any other config you're using if any.

Comment: Hi @mythz I added some extra info at the bottom of the question.

Comment: by Xamarin do you mean developing for Android or iOS?

Comment: Sorry, for iOS but since I am triggering it from a unit test I am bypassing the iOS library and directly accessing the portable library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs for using the [PCL clients and Json Serializer is in the HelloMobile project](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile), specifically you need to install the **ServiceStack.Client** NuGet package which contains the platform specific extensions required to support the platform you're running on:

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Client
```

For iOS you should also [explicitly initialize the PCL library](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile#initializing-pcl-client) with:

```
IosPclExportClient.Configure();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Basically I already have a Rest service and I just want to replace the newtonsoft library on my client side with the ServiceStack library because it is supposed to be faster. I am currently using  newtonsoft JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestDto>(@"{""MyProp"":6}"); and it works fine. But I thought I could simply replace this one dll with the ServiceStack dll.

Comment: @doorman Right, the PCL version of ServiceStack.Text.dll Serializers requires the `ServiceStack.Client` NuGet package, you don't need to use any of the client libraries, but the serializer does need to call out into the platform extensions to be able to use the most optimal code generation option that's for each available platform.

Comment: mythz it works to call the library when running it in the simulator. However it fails in the unit test because the ios project is not called. Do you know if it is possible to unit test a portable library which uses the ServiceStack library?

Comment: @doorman Not sure what you mean by "iOS project is not called", have you initialized the Client in the Unit Tests as well?